# Find original place of an element in array after deleting other elements

Tags: python, list, algorithm

I have a list of numbers. Assume it is a random selection of numbers in the range of 40.

I have a for loop that selects one index in each iteration. after finishing one round in the loop, I save the index I selected in a list and then delete it from the original list (so after each iteration one element is deleted from the original list).

```
perm = random.sample(range(1, 40), 30) 
for i in range(7):
   index = random.randrange(len(perm))
   perm.pop(index)
```

In the end, I have a list of indices showing the number of the index I deleted at each iteration say something like `l = [5, 15, 6, 7, 11, 3, 8]`. Is there an easy way to get the original place of these indices? (for example I deleted 5 first, so when I selected 15 it was actually in the 16th place in the original array and I want to find the original place of all indices)

I tried something simple like this:

```
for i in range(len(l)):
    for j in range(i):
        if l[i] >= l[j]:
            l[i] += 1
```

But it does not seem to be quite right. Any ideas on how to make it work with just one loop?

Comment: You need to keep a copy of the original list and a list of values you're removing from list.

Comment: @Carcigenicate This is a subproblem of a much bigger problem I'm working on and for that, I need to delete the index I selected after each iteration.

Comment: @pavel I need the indices, and there might be duplicate values in my original problem. So, unfortunately I can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
l = [5, 15, 6, 7, 11, 3, 8]

copy = l[:]
for i in range(len(l)):
    for j in range(i):
        l[i] += 1 if copy[i] >= copy[j] else 0

print(l)  # [5, 16, 7, 9, 14, 3, 12]
```

Like @pavel said, you need to make a working copy. Then your idea works fine.

Comment: Right now this code has quadratic runtime though. Im pretty sure you can sort the values first (n log n) and then for each value do binary search (so again n log n). This would overall result in n log n runtime.